# House robber - Python Syntax

Tags: python

My question is why the following syntax produces the correct answer for house robber:

```
last, now = 0, 0
for element in nums:
    last, now = now, max(last + element, now)
return now
```

vs the same thing, but not inline:

```
last, now = 0, 0
for element in nums:
    last = now
    now = max(last + element, now)
return now
```

I expect they should be the same. I traced this out though (in the second snippet) and it is giving me the wrong answer. For example: in an array [3, 5, 3] my given answer for the second code snippet will be 11 - it will just keep adding things.

I'm obviously missing something about the inline capabilities of python. Is there anyone that could provide some insight? Thank You.

Comment: Please enlighten me what a "house robber" is :)

Comment: Yes, I'm curious too

Comment: Oh! It is the leetcode question based on "Maximum sum of array such that no 2 elements chosen are indices adjacent" problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between your two pieces of code is that in the first example you have *one* assignment while in the second you have *two consecutive* assignments.

The line `last, now = now, max(last + element, now)` is one assignment statement.  The right side builds a `tuple` of two elements which is then assigned in one step to a tuple of two *lvalues* (i. e. two variables) on the left side of the operator.

The lines `last = now` and `now = max(last + element, now)`, however, are done in succession to each other, i. e. the first assignment is taking place first, then the second (which is affected by the first).

Minimal example:

```
a = 4
b = 3
a, b = b, a  # → a will be 3, b will be 4
```

vs.

```
a = 4
b = 3
a = b  # → a will be 3
b = a  # → b will be 3 as well
```

Comment: This is an amazing answer. thank you for the example and clarity.

Answer (score 0):

In the first code, both values are updated from the previous values of `last` and `now`.

In the second code, you first update `last` and then continue your computation with the new value (previously `now`).

Answer (score 0):

In the first code you change the variables `last` and `now` simultaneously, using (on the right side of the `=`) the old values of both:

```
    last, now = now, max(last + element, now)
```

In the second code snippet you first change `last` and then `now`, thereby using the changed `last`:

```
    last = now
    now = max(last + element, now)
```